# How to send data to Visual Form Builder form

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Module : Visual Form Builder

I need to send post values to one of my
website with visual form builder.

Basically I have this website where people fill up and when
the user submits the form , my website will also send that
data to one of my website with visual form builder .

I've been banging my head for 2 days now . 
still no lead to make it work.

*I am using php CURL. I've check cookies , csrf hidden field. etc.... still no luck ...

P.S ..  No I have no intention to spam websites..

Here is my code

```
<?php 

set_time_limit(9999999999999999);
require_once './simple_html_dom.php';
$GLOBALS['BASE_URL'] = "http://data.mysite.com";
$GLOBALS['cookieJar'] = "cookieTemp.txt";





function runCommand()
{
    $csrf_token  = getCSRFVal();
    $payload = array(
            "form_id" => "1",
            "vfb-6[0]" => "Other",
            "vfb-9" => "yes",
            "vfb-10" => "yes",
            "vfb-11" => "yes",
            "vfb-12" => "options",
            "vfb-14" => "test",
            "vfb-15" => "test",
            "vfb-16" => "447796272707",
            "_wp_http_referer" => "/",
            "_vfb-csrf-token" => $csrf_token,
        );
    $contentLength = strlen(http_build_query($payload));
    $request_header = array(
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch',
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fil;q=0.6,th;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,es;q=0.2',
            'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'Host:data.mysite.com',
            'Origin:http://data.mysite.com',
            'Referer:http://data.mysite.com/',
            'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Length:'.$contentLength,
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$GLOBALS['BASE_URL']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $request_header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $GLOBALS['cookieJar']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $GLOBALS['cookieJar']);
    $cur_res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $cur_res;
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);


}


function getCSRFVal()
{
    $request_header = array(
            'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fil;q=0.6,th;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,es;q=0.2',
            'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36',
        );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$GLOBALS['BASE_URL']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $request_header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $GLOBALS['cookieJar']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $GLOBALS['cookieJar']);

    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $html_object = str_get_html($page);
    curl_close($ch);    
    $tempCsrfToken = "";
    if (@$html_object->find("input[name='_vfb-csrf-token']",0)->value) {
        $tempCsrfToken = $html_object->find("input[name='_vfb-csrf-token']",0)->value;
    }else{
        echo "Cant get new csrf token";
        die();
    }
    return $tempCsrfToken;
}
runCommand();


?>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @cpilko Hi , I already added the code.